# Spring potential energy formula in 2D case

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, spring

In 1D case, the potential energy of a spring can be determined by

$$U = \frac{1}{2} k (x-x_0)^2$$

where $x$ and $x_0$ are final and initial spring lengths measured in x-axis respectively. I am trying to find a 2D version of this formula.

I started with 2D version of Hooke's law

$$\vec{F} = - k (l - l_0) \cos(\theta) \hat{x} + - k (l - l_0) \sin(\theta)\hat{y}$$

where $l$ and $l_0$ are final and initial spring lengths respectively independent of axis and $\theta$ is angle with respect to positive x-axis.

I know that potential energy can be found by this relation: $\vec{F}=-\nabla U$. Therefore

$$- k (l - l_0) \cos(\theta) \hat{x} + - k (l - l_0) \sin(\theta)\hat{y} = - \frac{dU}{dx} \hat{x} + - \frac{dU}{dy} \hat{y}$$

However when I calculate $U$, I get conflicting results,

$$U_1 = k (l - l_0) \cos(\theta) x$$

$$U_2 = k (l - l_0) \sin(\theta) y$$

Which part I did wrong? What is the correct version of 2D spring potential energy formula?

Comment: If you are using coordinates, it might be good to express everything in rectangular coordinates. What is $l \cos\theta$?

Comment: @robphy length of stretched spring measured from x-axis?

Comment: Can $l\cos\theta$ be expressed in rectangular coordinates?

Comment: @robphy I don't understand what you are asking. By rectangular coordinates, I assume you meant Cartesian coordinates. I am using Cartesian in my question.

Comment: Is $x=l\cos\theta$ ?

Comment: @robphy Yes, I think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get to the point
$$
- k (l - l_0) \cos(\theta) \hat{x} + - k (l - l_0) \sin(\theta)\hat{y} = - \frac{dU}{dx} \hat{x} - \frac{dU}{dy} \hat{y}\,,
$$
those total derivatives should really be *partial* derivatives.  In addition, $l$ and $\theta$ are coordinates.  The upshot then is that you can't solve the component differential equations by pretending that the components are constant.

Instead, note that $x=l\cos\theta$, $y=l\sin\theta$, and so $x_0=l_0\cos\theta$ and $y_0=l_0\sin\theta$, in which case you get the two differential equations,
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = -k (x-x_0)\,,~~~~~~~
\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = -k (y-y_0)y\,.
$$
Solving the first, we get
$$
U(x, y) = -\frac{1}{2}k (x-x_0)^2 + f(y)\,,
$$
where $f(y)$ is *some* function of $y$.  We have to bring out this integration constant because of the partial derivatives.  For the other equation, we solve to get
$$
U(x, y) = -\frac{1}{2}k (y-y_0)^2 + g(x)\,,
$$
where again the integration "constant" $g(x)$ comes out because the partial derivative of $g(x)$ with respect to $y$ is zero.  We can then identify
$g(x)$ as $-k(x-x_0)^2/2$ and $f(y)$ as $-k(y-y_0)^2/2$, leaving
$$
U(x,y) = -\frac{1}{2}k (x-x_0)^2 -\frac{1}{2}k (y-y_0)^2 = -\frac{1}{2}k ((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2)\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand better now. But can you expand bit more on finding integration constants $f(y)$ and $g(x)$? So the final $U(x,y)$ can be found by simply adding two $U$s solved in differential equations?

Comment: This really comes from taking some multivariable calculus courses.  But it goes like this.  When you solve a differential equation, you get an integration constant, i.e. $f'(x) = x/2$ implies that $f(x) = x^2 + c$. When your function is a multivariable function, then the integration constant can depend on the *other* variable: i.e. if $\partial f (x, y)/\partial x = x/2$, then $ f(x, y) = x^2 + c$, just like before, except now the $c$ can depend on $y$ because the particle with respect to $x$ kills any $y$ terms.  Just take the gradient of the function that I got to see that it matches!

Comment: I just finished multivariable calculus and differential equations last term but I'm still not fully used to these new mathematics so forgive me. I still don't understand why $g(x)$ is $-kx^2/2$ not $-k(x-x_0)^2/2$ and vice versa.

Comment: That’s a typo that I forgot to fix I’ll fix it later.